# Django Success Message in view using django.contrib.messages

Tags: javascript, python, django

I am working on a system which allows a user to place a booking for an event for a Player object registered to their account. Previously I had the system redirecting to home page on success but I decided to try and implement a tool tip style pop up when the booking has been successful.

I've tried a couple of things for this and none have quite worked for me. First I tried adding "message = 'Booking Successful.'" in my render command, along with a script in the html template. This gave me "render() got an unexpected keyword argument 'message'".

Then I tried added it to the context dictionary after my form such that the render request reads:

```
return render(request, 'tennis/make_booking.html', {'event_form': event_form, 'message': 'Booking Successful'})
```

This technically works but the message is displayed on page loading which isn't quite right.

Then finally I tried a call to the Django message function as shown in my below code. This code pops up an empty message box when I load the page and when I click the book button it gives me an error which I'll provide the full stack trace of.

EDIT: Ignore all above, code below adds a line of text to the page on successful booking. This is better than I had but I would like it to be a pop up if possible.

views.py

```
@login_required
def make_booking(request):
    form = EventForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
       event_form = EventForm(request.POST)
       print "HELLO"
       if event_form.is_valid():
          print "VALID"

          event = event_form.save(commit=False)
          player = request.user.player_set.all()[0]
          event.player = player
          event.save()
          # Consider rendering a different page
          messages.success(request, 'Your booking was successful!', extra_tags='alert')
       else:
            # invalid form, print problems to terminal
            print(event_form.errors)
    else:
         # not POST so render blank forms
         event_form = EventForm()
    return render(request, 'tennis/make_booking.html', {'event_form': event_form})
```

HTML template:

```
{% extends 'tennis/base.html' %}

{% block body_block%}

    {% block title_block %}
        Make a Booking
    {% endblock %}

    <body>
        <h1> Book an Event </h1>
        If booking is sucessful you will be redirected to the home page
        <br>
        <div>
            <form id="event_form" method="post" action="/tennis/make_booking/">
               {% csrf_token %}
               {% for hidden in event_form.hidden_fields %}
                  {{ hidden }}
               {% endfor %}
               {% for field in event_form.visible_fields %}
                  {{field.errors}}
               {% endfor %}
               <p>{{ event_form.event.label_tag }} {{ event_form.event }}</p>
               <input type="submit" name="book" value="Book"/>
             </form>
        </div>
        {% if messages %}
            <ul class="messages">
                {% for message in messages %}
                    <li class="{{ message.tags }}">{{ message }}</li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        {% endif %}
    </body>

{% endblock %}
```

How can I modify this code such that I get a success message popping up when I click my book button instead of just a line of text added to the page?

Comment: change  `messages.book_message` to  `messages.success`
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django comes with a built-in messages app  that you can easily add to your project.

Read this part of the docs on [Displaying messages to users in django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/messages/)
and also this [blog post](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tips/2016/09/06/django-tip-14-messages-framework.html) for a quick tutorial on using displaying response messages in django.

You're also getting that specific error because `'book_message'` is not an attribute of the messages module  so change it from `messages.book_message` to `messages.success`

Comment: I have been trying to use it but I didn't get anything useful from the documentation pages I read. I'll have a look at your links just now and see if I can make it work, thank you.

Comment: Okay I used the tutorial you linked (very useful, thanks) and I now have the application outputting a line of text onto the template on success. How can I make this a pop up instead? Question updated with how my code looks now.

Comment: if you want a pop-up then you will need to write javascript to do that, Take a look at modals.